# slice and replace string before assigns to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was looking, to replace and slice a string/text before assigns to a variable,
but I did in two, I want to know if this can be done.

**Example:**

```
    SET MY_TIME=%%time:~0,8%::=_%
    ECHO %MY_TIME%
    #output: %12:50:47::=_%
```

My current result, because i didn't find the way to replace and slice in the same line..

```
    SET GET_TIME=%time:~0,8%
    SET MY_TIME=%GET_TIME::=_%
    ECHO %MY_TIME%
    #output: 12_42_48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd` does not allow for multiple inline replacements, as you have already learned. The closest you will probably get is:

from `cmd`:

```
set "mytime=%time:~0,8%" & call echo %mytime::=_%
```

From batch-file:

```
set "mytime=%time:~0,8%" & call echo %%mytime::=_%%
```

As a side note, if you want to retain the format, you need to consider single digit hours to be amended as well:

```
set "mytime=%time =%
```

The above will replace the whitespace before a single digit hour (1am to 9am) with a zero, which retains your format `hhmmss`

When getting to this however, there is no longer a purpose to run it as a one liner and you might as well add it line by line:

```
set "mytime=%time:~0,8%"
set "mytime=%mytime: =0%"
echo %mytime::=_%
```